# how to upgrade angular project to a specific version along with the dependencies

Tags: angular, npm

I'm re-starting an older angular project. I want to update it to a specific version and also all the dependencies that it uses to the latest ones.
I tried uninstalling the cli version first and then update it.
What should I do next. Can I change the versions manually on the package.json folder and then simply ng serve run it.

Comment: Have you read https://update.angular.io/?

Comment: Thanks, just one question I need to be version-specific (i.e to version 7). Will this update it to 8 ?

Comment: Did you actually read it?

Comment: The documentation says "Update all of your Angular framework packages to v6", how to manually achieve this? Should I use npm udpate *package-name*@6.x.x.
but then is it possible to directly migrate from v5 to v7 without updating to v6 first ?
https://update.angular.io/#5.2:7.0

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ng update`

[More Details](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/specifications/update.md)

Comment: I suppose with ng update, all the dependencies are updated to the latest version, which i dont want as i want to work with version 7

Comment: there is an option for that with ng update --to <version>

Comment: The documentation says "Update all of your Angular framework packages to v6", how to manually achieve this? Should I use npm udpate *package-name*@6.x.x.
but then is it possible to directly migrate from v5 to v7 without updating to v6 first ? -
https://update.angular.io/#5.2:7.0

Answer (score 0):

Please don't run 'ng update' cmd unless your trying to update angular to the latest version 17 .

Firstly, u have to update the following as per your required specific version;

```
npm install
npm uninstall --save-dev angular/cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@<specific version>
npm install --save-dev @angular/core@<specific version>  
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@<specific version> <= check the compatibility with the version ur try to upgrade to.

npm update
npm outdated  <= will identify packages that should be update
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
npm install
```

After that , try to update the dependencies one by one using remove and add command (do check the compatibility with your version before running this command);

```
npm remove @angular/cdk 
npm add @angular/cdk@8
```

[*//-----------dont touch the below lines and the one having less version than 7 check them one by one ;

```
"@swimlane/dragula": "3.7.3",
"@angular/http": "7.2.1",
"@types/prismjs": "1.9.0",
"ag-grid-community": "20.0.0",
```

]

Later, after running the above commands, run:

```bash
npm update
```

Try to install the typescript as per your specfic version requirement

```bash
npm install typescript@">=3.4.0 and <3.6.0" --save-dev
ng s
```

Finally solve any errors that occurs as per your requirements.